# SCSS selectors, can I get a elm in a child of a parent

Tags: html, css, sass

So I have a HTML structure like this:

```
<g>
    <text></text>
</g>
<g>
    <g> 
        <path></path>
    </g>
    <g> 
        <text></text>
    </g>
</g>
```

And I want to change the text elements css after a psudeo :hover from path, can I target this somehow with SCSS? Here is what I have so are:

```
g{
   path{
     &:hover {
        && + g{
           text{
              opacity: 1.0 !important;
              filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
```

So I just want to grab the side by g tag from the path tags css, is this possible?

Comment: Perphaps this can help you out: https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: The `text` cannot be affected by a subsequest sibling or descendant...you can't go back up the DOM.

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, **only post the compiled CSS**.

Answer (score 2):

In CSS you are not able to address a parent from a specific action on a child element ... as SASS only generates CSS it's then impossible too.

A solution could be to put a text element in each path elements (or g elements containing path) and then, to write :

HTML :

```
<g>
    <g> 
        <path>
             <text></text>
        </path>
    </g>
</g>
```

SCSS :

```
g {
   g:hover > path > text {
       color: #FFF;
   }
}
```

If you don't want to modify HTML structure, and want to modify the style of a parent element from the hover pseudo selector of a child, you should use Javascript or a Javascript framework/library (like jQuery, Angular, React, ...).